# jQuery Datatables, Select/Deselect handlers does not work after

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using DataTables with buttons and select.

The table's destroy is set to true, because in some places I have to reload the table (not sure relevant)

I got table.on('select' / 'deselect' event handlers

All of the above inside a single method I call in a few places (like document ready, but also other places I need to reload the table)

All works fine after the table have loaded the first time, but when I call the method again, thus the table reload, the select/deselect event handlers), however after that the select event handler gives this error
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'node' of undefined`

The code for the event handlers looks like this

```
        table.on('select',
            function() {
                var selectedRows = table.rows({ selected: true });
                table.button(1).enable(selectedRows.count() > 0);
                table.button(2).enable(selectedRows.count() === 1);
            }
        );
```

Comment: Do you detach event handler for `select` event when you re-initialize your table with [`off()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/off()) API method before attaching it?

Comment: Thank you @Gyrocode.com, that did it

Answer (score 1):

My problem was a bit different as I was mixing the select and deselect on the same event handler, but the handler was not firing:

```
table.on('deselect select', function () {
    console.log("Code is not reached");
});
```

What fixed the issue for me was to add the .dt namespace per the recommendation on the DataTables forum

https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/36458/bug-cannot-combine-select-deselect-event-handlers

```
.on("select.dt deselect.dt",  ...
```

Even though my problem was not linked to reloading the DataTable, a google search brought me here, so that is why I am sharing!